# Customize width of column bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In the documentation of Bootstrap 4, I only find the possibility to modify the width of the gutter ($grid-gutter-width) .
I would like to change the width of the column.
How can I do it?

My code SASS:

```
$grid-columns: 12;
$grid-gutter-width: 40px;
```

I have to do this setting:
[screen settings sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHQkF.png)

Thanks

Comment: So, do I correctly understand that you want to change the main container width? That's in a map: $container-max-widths
- but then the actual width of the column of course still depends on the screen size and the number of columns.

Comment: To change the maximum width of the container, I created a .wrapper class with max-width:1440px; I want to set the width of my column to 92px as seen on the screenshot.

Comment: You can't set the width of a column to a px value in bootstrap, as it is a responsive grid, which uses relative sizes (%) so it will work with different screen sizes. You can calculate the max width of the container though to achieve this:
92px * 12 (columns) + 22px * 11 (gutters) = 1346px max width. If you set your container-max-width to that, the columns should be 92px in the largest screen size.

Comment: Change the width of what column? Please post the HTML code that demonstrates the issue. Bootstrap has many different sized "columns".

Comment: This is indeed the right solution $container-max-widths on 1346px and grid-gutter-width on 22px and it imitates the graphic model  (sketch file) rather well. Thanks for the explanation with the calculation.